Rsyslog help examples new to linux
Iv search the web, and im learning, but still having issues with figuring out how to configure the conf. files.
i have ubuntu 22 server, and i have fortigate firewalls, and dell switches, and few pc's, and all units are sending rsyslog files to the ubuntu server.  (all jammed into one log file.) i see the fortigate 60f, and dell Switch, and the pc's info, ect...
but what i need help with is...
Putting all firewalls into a folder, into one log file, with date.
then put all switches into different folder, into one log file with date,
and pc.
would this go into the rsyslog.conf. / or the 50-default.conf / or the logrotate.conf /
i just cant find any examples on the web about how to put it into folders.
or if there is a cheat sheet out there. but iv been searching for 2 weeks,
Please help, thanks.
